# Matching only a single number in a series of numbers in grep

Tags: grep

If I have a file like:

```
hostname1.domain.com
hostname2.domain.com
hostname3.domain.com
hostname23.domain.com
hostname1234.domain.com
```

How can I `grep` to only return:

```
hostname1.domain.com
hostname2.domain.com
hostname3.domain.com
```

Such that I'm only getting a single number returned. I am trying:

```
grep -E hostname[+1,+2,+3].domain.com
```

Which seems to work, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: why are you putting "+" before the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do:

```
grep 'hostname[0-9]\.domain\.com' infile
```

`[0-9]` matches single digit between 0~9, you need escape dots `.` to match on dot literally otherwise that means match any single character (but newline); and always quote your patterns to avoid shell interpretation on special things like globbing, brace expansion or others.

if you want restrict this only to hostname1, 2 and 3, you can do :

```
grep 'hostname[123]\.domain\.com' infile
```

or equivalently:

```
grep 'hostname[1-3]\.domain\.com' infile
```

you may also wan to use `-x` (Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line or alternatively surrounding it with `^` start of line and `$` end of line anchors.)

```
grep -x 'hostname[0-9]\.domain\.com' infile
grep  '^hostname[0-9]\.domain\.com$' infile
```

to match exactly for string like `hostname23.domain.com` and not anything else:

```
grep -xF 'hostname23.domain.com' infile
```

see [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for the `-F` switch and why we didn't escape dots here.

Comment: Swell. Might be more suitable for a separate question, but out of curiosity if I wanted just to find `hostname23.domain.com` and nothing else, how can I find just the `23`?

Comment: @Kahn Ask a separate question, and be sure to mention what part of the line you want to search with (the exact text of the whole line, or a pattern using the `23` substring only). In the context of the current question, where you search with most of the whole hostname, you would use `grep -Fx 'hostname23.domain.com' infile` to do a string comparison matching against complete lines.

Comment: @Kahn see the edit